# Uncaught error in Promise

Tags: angular, angular-services

When trying to do an API call to my backend the Angular application crashes with these debuging information:

```js
          ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk 1 failed.
onScriptComplete@http://127.0.0.1:4200/inline.bundle.js:92:33
wrapFn@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6539:30
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:5908:17
onInvokeTask@http://127.0.0.1:4200/vendor.bundle.js:4382:28
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:5907:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:5675:28
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:5970:28

Stacktrace:
resolvePromise@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6253:31
resolvePromise@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6224:17
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6301:17
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:5908:17
onInvokeTask@http://127.0.0.1:4200/vendor.bundle.js:4382:28
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:5907:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:5675:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6068:25
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:5974:25
```

I would like to know how I can get more detailed debugging information? Mine consol.log statements doesn't work is this normal?

What can be the source of these error? It looks there is something off on my promise in mine services but i don't find the the error.

user.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http} from "@angular/http";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


export class UserLogin{
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
export class LoginToken{
    token: string
}

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private loginUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login/';  // URL to web api
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    private UserLogin: UserLogin;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public login(username: string, password: string): Promise<LoginToken> {
        console.log(username);
        this.UserLogin.username = username;
        this.UserLogin.password = password;
        console.log(this.UserLogin);
        return this.http
                .post(this.loginUrl,JSON.stringify(this.UserLogin), {headers: this.headers})
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => response.json().data as LoginToken)
                .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

}
```

login.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {UserService} from "../shared/services/user.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent{
    constructor(
        public router: Router,
        private UserService: UserService,
    ) { }


    username: string = "";
    password: string = "";
    token: string = "";


    login(){
        console.log(this.username);
        console.log(this.password);
        this.UserService.login(this.username, this.password)
            .then(token => this.token = token.token);

        localStorage.setItem('loginToken', this.token);
        localStorage.setItem('isLoggedin', 'true');
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the network panel of your browser dev tools say? Which requests do you see, what's their URL, method and response status? What is the address in the navigation bar of your browser?

Comment: It does an GET request to 1.chunk.js an then it redownloads the complete application (dashboard, inline.bundle.js, ...). All the status codes are 200 and only GET requests (except for the websocket that has status code 101).

Comment: The login page is on /login and when pressing log in it goes to /dashboard where it reloads the application (start loading page). The loading page will then link to /login because nobody is logged in.

Comment: I'm lost: why would an HTTP AJAX request to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login/ load a chunk.js file, then cause a navigation to /dashboard, and reload the whole application? Are you sure the login button invokes the login metod of your component?

Comment: Thanks I found mine error it is not in the function but in my html page I did an  [routerLink]="['/dashbord'] before the (click)="login()" so the function didn't run. Thank you for the help!